# Creating objects from parsed file

Tags: python, beginner, parsing, io

I'm newbie in Python but I want to know some tricks to make my code look cute. I know that syntax of Python allows to do this, but I don't know how.
Suppose I have file with lines of format "x y z" and I want to parse it and make some objects. Now code looks like this:

```
class Point(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y, z):
        self.x = x;
        self.y = y;
        self.z = z;

...

def load_file(file_path):
    points = [];
    with open(file_path, "r") as input_file:
        for line in input_file:
            str_point = line.split();
            x = float(str_point[0]);
            y = float(str_point[1]);
            z = float(str_point[2]);
            points.append(Point(x, y, z));
    return points;
```

Is there any way to make this code simpler?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of parsing `x`, `y`, `z` one by one, you can use a list comprehension,
and pass the whole thing directly to the the constructor of `Point` using `*` like this:

```
def load_file(file_path):
    objects = []
    with open(file_path) as input_file:
        for line in input_file:
            obj = Point(*[float(x) for x in line.split()])
            objects.append(obj)
    return objects
```

I dropped the `"r"` in `open(..., "r")`, as that's the default anyway.
Even more importantly,
`;` are not required to end statements in Python,
and they are just noise in the posted code.

It would be even *cuter* to use a generator pattern instead:

```
def load_file(file_path):
    with open(file_path) as input_file:
        for line in input_file:
            yield Point(*[float(x) for x in line.split()])
```

You could iterate over this to do something with the objects, for example:

```
for obj in load_file(file_path):
    # do something ...
```

Or you could load all into a list using a list comprehension:

```
objects = [x for x in load_file(file_path)]
```